# What is the most efficient way to calculate the sine of a rational number?

Tags: trigonometry, computational-mathematics

I'm happy  that we can use some trig identities like $$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \equiv \pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{2}}$$ and $$\sin(\alpha \pm\beta) \equiv \sin(\alpha) \cos(\beta)\pm \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$ (and many more) to calculate exactly, for example, $\sin(15^\circ)=\sin\left(\frac{30^\circ}{2}\right)$
and $\sin(75^\circ)=\sin(90^\circ-15^\circ)$, but it seems that the smaller the angle of which I want to find the sine, the more identities I have to use, so, to calculate, for example, $\sin(1^\circ)$, is very fiddly and tedious.

My question is:

> What is the most efficient way to calculate the sine of any rational angle (in as few steps as possible)?
>
> Is there some algorithm for doing this?

---

P.S. I'm aware of [this](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf), which gives $\sin(\theta)$ for $\theta \in[0^\circ,90^\circ] \cap \mathbb{Z}$, but I'd like to be able to *calculate*, for example, $\sin\left(\frac1{12}\right)$ (exactly).

Comment: Is your goal to locate, say $y = \sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$, on the real number line?  To be able to say things like $0.01745 < y < 0.01746$?  In that case, the approximation by using *enough* terms in the Taylor series (Maclaurin series) is great.  [cont'd...]

Comment: Halving formula won't give yoou exact values unless you restrict to special rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: [...cont'd] Or do you want to know **exact** statements, such as the fact that $x = \cos(\frac{\pi}{5})$ is the positive root of the polynomial $4x^2 - 2x - 1$?  These require finding roots of polynomial equations, a daunting (and usually *impossible* in radicals) task if the degrees are large.

Comment: Finding $\sin(1^\circ)$ involves solving a cubic equation (in the casus irreducibilis), so unless you are content with radicals of complex numbers, you are stuck.

Comment: I imagine an equivalent formulation of this question is: "Which angles are constructible via compass and straightedge, and what is the algorithm for constructing those that are?" That would be something else you could search under.

Comment: @Semiclassical: As long as you stick to rational multiples of $\pi$ as in the original question, this is fully answered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I'm surprised by the requirement about the angle being a rational multiple of $\pi$. I'd have figured that anything not commensurate with $\pi$ wouldn't ever be constructible by compass and straightedge.

Comment: @Semiclassical: You can easily construct e.g. arctan(2), which is an irrational (in fact, transcendental) multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek) I see your point: the constructibility is due to the value of the corresponding trig functions, not due to the angle being rational per se.

Comment: I just want to point out that below about 12∘, sin(θ) *equals* θ within 1%, and below 1∘, the error is less than 0.005%.  You have to express everything in radians like a normal person, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exact answers may not have closed forms for sufficiently small angles but the general method is as follows

Say we know the exact answer to $\sin(u)$ and now want to calculate $\sin(\frac{u}{k})$

For an integer $k$

$$\sin(k\theta)$$

In general by using the rule derived from the angle sum formula:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product-to-sum_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles

One can expand this out into a large sum of sines and cosines

Now for each of the cosines one can substitute

$$\cos(x) = \sqrt{1 - \sin(x)^2}$$

To get an expression of the form

$$\sin(k \theta) = SOME \ HAIRY \ ALGEBRAIC \ MESS \ FOR \ SUFFICIENTLY \ LARGE \ K$$

Nevertheless we can now "solve" our equation above for $\sin(\theta)$ which allows us to expressed

$$\sin(\theta) = F(\sin(k\theta))$$

Where F is the, generally more complex inverse to the algebraic expression earlier.

Now substitute $u = k \theta, \rightarrow \theta = \frac{u}{k}$

And you've got yourself a formula for integer divisions of angles

So you can actually get exact formulas for ANY and ALL Rational Numbers.

There is one slight crux to this all. The answers can no longer be expressed in radicals when consider rational numbers whose denominators are a multiple of a prime greater than or equal to 5 because in order to express such rational numbers one EVENTUALLY is forced to solve a polynomial of degree 5 or greater (in the attempt to invert the $\sin(x)$ expression) and in general this is not solvable.

But at least you can always get an exact algebraic answer if you extend your set of tools to include ultra-radicals

To see a worked example: consider

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

(I am cheating and using a prepared identity instead of attempting to trudge through with the angle sum identity, i assure you both methods work)

now some algebraic hocus-pocus

$$\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x)\sqrt{1 - \sin(x)^2}$$
$$\sin(2x)^2 = 4 \sin(x)^2 (1 - \sin(x)^2)$$
$$4\sin(x)^4 - 4\sin(x)^2 + \sin(2x)^2 = 0$$

And then we bring out the big gunz... meaning the Quadratic Formula (I'll grab the positive have for now although both choices are valid)

$$\sin(x)^2 = \frac{4 + \sqrt{16 - 16\sin(2x)^2}}{8}$$
$$\sin(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin(2x)^2}}{2}}$$

Meaning

$$\sin(\frac{x}{2}) = \sqrt{\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin(x)^2}}{2}}$$

Course we can get even fancier by looking at something along the lines of

$$\sin \left(\frac{x}{4} \right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - {\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin(x)^2}}{2}}}}{2}} $$

etc... the possibilities are endless. Once you determine

$$\sin(\frac{x}{prime})$$

the multiples of that prime all become accessible (assuming you know the other prime factors as well)

To subdivide by 3 it seems:

$$\sin\left( \frac{x}{3} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 1} - \sin(x)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 1} - \sin(x)}} \right) $$

so combining my earlier formula with this one:

$$ \sin \left( \frac{x}{12} \right) =  \sqrt{\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - {\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 1} - \sin(x)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 1} - \sin(x)}} \right) \right)^2}}{2}}}}{2}} $$

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical for more information about Ultraradicals

Comment: And that's all there is to it. No problemo.

Comment: Bring radicals can only solve equations of degree 5, not higher. On the other hand, sine of a rational multiple of $\pi$ is the real part of a root of unity, hence it is always solvable in plain radicals (of complex arguments).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  what then is notation then for even higher radicals for degree 6,7... n? Also ^ that is very good to know. is there a proof for that I can find anywhere?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Excellent answer. Thanks! Is this the most efficient method?

Comment: @alexqwx haha This is probably the least efficient method, since I wait until the absolute end to do any sort of simplifying. But the theory of simplifying radicals is complex and currently an active area of research (see: Landau's Algorithm) for more information

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: I can’t parse the first sentence of your comment. As for the second, if you are referring to solvability of roots of unity in radicals, this follows from basic Galois theory. See e.g. http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/personal-pages/weber/publications/pdf/WeberA/WeberKeckeisen99a.pdf .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thanks for the link! as for the comment what I mean to say is: degree 5,6,7 ... (all integers greater than 5) polynomials are generally known to be unsolvable in radicals. Given that, in order to solve them additional radical tools will be required such as Bring Radicals for degree 5 equations. Where can I find the general set of additional radicals that is used for all equations of arbitrary high order (i imagine there will be infinitely such new radicals required and therefore a general "rule" for generating them will be necessary)

Comment: There is no such general set, that’s the point. (This is kind of explained in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61409 .) You should think of solving higher degree algebraic equations as a primitive operation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek the asker requires there set to be "finite" what if its an infinite set (for example a special radical for the 5 case, one for the 6 case, etc...) such that there are infinitely many such new tools introduced. For example can it be said that if one defines $Q(n,a) = x | x^n - x + a = 0$ then every polynomial has a solution in terms of radicals and this new "Q" operator?

Comment: No. The question there asks for finite sets, but the answer is much more general. In particular, the solution of Hilbert’s sextic conjecture by Abhyankar basically means that solutions to generic degree-6 polynomials cannot be expressed using *any* family of one-variable algebraic functions (such as your $Q(n,-)$, which you wrote as two-variable, but is really a countable set of one-variable functions indexed by $n$).

Comment: It may be interesting to note that the sine and cosine of $\pi/p$ for $p=3,5,17,257,65537$ are all constructible, and so can be computed with just square roots.

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos(54)=\sin(36) $$

$$\cos(54)=\cos(3\times 18)=4\cos^3(18)-3\cos(18)$$
$$\sin(36)=\sin(2\times 18)=2\sin(18)\cos(18)$$

so $$2\sin(18)=4\cos^2(18)-3$$
now simple calculation shows that $$\sin(18)=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$
so
$$\sin(3)=\sin(18-15)=\sin(18)\cos(15)-\cos(18)\sin(15)$$

$\sin(1)$ will be the root of :

$$3\sin(1)-4\sin^3(1)=\sin(3)$$

but solution of the above gives a value involved with too many radicals and complex numbers $i=\sqrt{-1}$ such that it's actually efficient part is real part , it means imaginary part is zero .

for calculating $\sin(\frac{1}{12})$ it sufficent to calculate $\sin (\frac{1}{2})$ then $\sin (\frac{1}{4})$. and calculate $\sin (\frac{1}{3})$ by $3\sin(\frac{1}{3})-4\sin^3(\frac{1}{3})=\sin(1)$ and then $$\sin(\frac{1}{12})=\sin(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})$$

Comment: Solving that last equation (for $\sin 1^\circ$) (by Cardano to get an exact answer) necessitates calculation of complex cubic roots. Guess what, calculating a complex cubic root necessitates the calculation of cosine/sine of an angle divide by three. HALP! We're in a loop!

Comment: when we have 3 root in cubic ,then by Cardano , we could find all roots but when we want to express two of them in well known function we could use $4cos^3(x)-3cos(x)=cos(3x)$ trick.

Answer (score 4):

The most computationally-simple method I can think of is the Taylor series. This is how computers do it:

$$\sin(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!} = x + \dfrac{x^3}{3!}+ \dfrac{x^5}{5!}+ \dfrac{x^7}{7!}+ \dfrac{x^9}{9!}+ \dfrac{x^{11}}{11!} +\ ...$$

Plug in a few sample $x$ and $n$ values, and you'll see that the factorial term in the denominator comes to dominate, trending progressively higher terms toward zero and thus the sum toward a definite value. So eventually, you get "close enough" with a finite number of terms of the series. This series is pretty simple to generate; keep a total, the value of the last term generated and the number N of the last factorial in the denominator, then to generate the next term, multiply the previous term by X and divide by N(N-1).

As far as "exactly", well, you can keep going on pencil and paper as long as you want, but there are a lot of common irrational sines; $sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, for instance. From a practical and pragmatic standpoint, sooner or later you stop after you have enough sig figs for a real-world calculation.

Comment: Close but not exact...

Comment: This is a scheme to **approximate** the values.  The OP is asking about **exact** values, no?

Comment: Are you sure that this is how calculators do it? I have always thought that calculators use [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC).

Comment: From the article you linked, CORDIC is used in computational circuits that don't have hardware multipliers. The Taylor series has lower space requirements (CORDIC requires a table of precomputed values; the T-S can be calculated from scratch) but requires a high-bitcount AU and ideally an FPU to be efficient, both of which are standard equipment on practically every desktop CPU (and then laptop/mobile) manufactured since the mid-90s.

Answer (score 2):

For positive integers $m$ and $n$, $(-1)^m = \cos(m \pi) = T_n(\cos(m \pi/n))$, where $T_n$ is the $n$'th [Chebyshev polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomial) of the first kind.  So $\cos(m \pi/n)$ is one of the roots of the polynomial $T_n(z) - (-1)^m$, and of course $\sin(m \pi/n) = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(m \pi/n)}$.

Comment: Quite the opposite, $\cos(m\pi n)$ (and thus $\sin(m\pi/n)$) is always expressible using radicals. Its splitting field is just $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2n})\cap\mathbb R$, assuming $(n,m)=1$.

Comment: Oops, sorry for that... I removed the statement about radicals.